# Prove the average quantum mechanical energy using l'Hôpital's rule

Tags: calculus, physics

I am trying to prove that taking the limit as $h\to0$ for the average quantum mechanical energy $$\dfrac{hν}{e^{hν/kBT}−1}$$ yields the average classical energy, $kBT$. How would you use l'Hôpital's rule for this?

Comment: I assume you mean $e^{h\nu / kBT} - 1$ for the denominator? In that case, the derivative will simply give a factor of $\nu / kBT$ in the denominator, and cancellation gives the desired result.

Comment: Yes, but how do you get the desired result.

Comment: Can you take the derivatives of the numerator and denominator individually? Then what does L'Hospital's rule tell you?

Comment: OKay, I remember now Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Using the fact that the derivative of $e^{h\alpha}$ is $\alpha e^{h\alpha}$, we find that

\begin{align*}
\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{h\nu}{e^{h\nu / kBT} - 1} &= \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{\nu}{\dfrac{\nu}{kBT} e^{h\nu/kBT}}\\ 
&= \dfrac{\nu}{\frac{\nu}{kBT}} \\ &= kBT
\end{align*}

were we have used that $e^0 = 1$ to evaluate the limit.

Answer (score 1):

Remember the fundamental limit $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x-1}{x}=1$ so that your limit is $kBT$.

Comment: But how does that help?

Comment: Let $x=\frac{h\nu}{kBT}$ (for $h\to 0$ then $x\to 0$) so that your function is $kBT\frac{x}{e^x-1}=\frac{kBT}{\frac{e^x-1}{x}}$ and $kBT$ is a constant....